# How to make the DHT11 sensor work with direct memory access(dev/mem method)?

Tags: gpio, c

So, I'm trying to make the DHT11 sensor work without any library on a Raspberry Pi 2 using C. I'm using **[this](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15)** tutorial to manipulate the GPIO pins registers so i can set them as input,output, HIGH and LOW. I am also using the wiringPi library to be sure that the timers are correct when sending initialization signals to the DHT11 sensor.

Here is the code that i am trying to make work:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "RPI.h"

#define MAXTIMINGS 85

int dht11_dat[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int read_GPIO(int number)
{
    if(GPIO_READ(number))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
void read_dht11_dat()
{

   uint8_t laststate    = 1;
   uint8_t counter      = 0;
   uint8_t j        = 0, i;
   float    f; /* fahrenheit */

   dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

   if(map_peripheral(&gpio) == -1)
   {
       printf("Failed to map the physical GPIO register!");
   }

   INP_GPIO(4);//befot output, must set as INPUT
   OUT_GPIO(4);//set outout
   /* pull pin down for 18 milliseconds */
   GPIO_CLR = 1 << 4;
   delay( 18 );
   /* then pull it up for 40 microseconds */
   GPIO_SET = 1 << 4; //    digitalWrite(7, HIGH );
   delayMicroseconds( 40 );
   /* prepare to read the pin */
   INP_GPIO(4);//pinMode( 7, INPUT );


   /* detect change and read data */
   for ( i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++ )
   {
       counter = 0;

       while ( read_GPIO(4) == laststate )
       {
           counter++;
           delayMicroseconds( 1 );
           if ( counter == 255 )
           {
               break;
           }
       }

       laststate = read_GPIO(4);/*digitalRead( 7 );*/

       if ( counter == 255 )
           break;

       /* ignore first 3 transitions */
       if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
       {
           /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
           dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
           if ( counter > 16 )
               dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
           j++;
       }
   }

/*
 * check we read 40 bits (8bit x 5 ) + verify checksum in the last byte
 * print it out if data is good
 */
if ( (j >= 40) && (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
{
    f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
    printf( "Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d *C (%.1f *F)\n",
        dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f );
}
else  {
    printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
}


//unmap_peripheral(&gpio); should this be here, im confused is this restarting the state of the gpio pin
}

 int main()
 {

   printf( "Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT11 Temperature test program\n" );

   if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
       exit( 1 );

   while ( 1 )
   {
       read_dht11_dat();
       delay( 1000 ); /* wait 1sec to refresh */
   }
   return 0;

}
```

So my question is why is this not working? When I test the GPIO manipulations with a simple blinking LED program everything is working OK.
I assume that the problem is in the INP_GPIO, OUT_GPIO, when they are called more than once the addresses of the registers are not set appropriate. Is there a way i can somehow "restart" the gpio pins original state at the beginning of the function? I guess this will fix my problem?

Correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: You are using a library.  I'm not quite sure what distinction you are making between using wirinPi and any other library.  None of the methods you are using will reliably read the DHT11.

Comment: I am using the library that i linked above so you can see how the gpio manipulation is done. And im using the wiringPi just for the timers. The code is giving me output if i substitute the INP_GPIO and the others manipulationa with the wiringPi ones.

Comment: I've pointed you to code before which sets GPIO modes.  Using macros instead of functions is a pretty pointless exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for the DHT11 sensor working without any external libraries on the Raspberry Pi 2. If you need any info on the functions just ***man*** them.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BCM2708_BASE (0x3F000000)
#define GPIO_BASE (BCM2708_BASE + 0x200000)
#define BLOCK_SIZE (4096)
#define MAXTIMINGS 85

struct bcm2835_peripheral
{
    int mem_fd;
    void *map;
    volatile unsigned int *addr;//address of mapped area
};
struct bcm2835_peripheral gpio;

/*
 *Mapping memory areas with mmap function will provide our program a direct access to device memory
 *Parameters: structrure for the addresses of the specified mapped memory areas
 */

int map_peripheral(struct bcm2835_peripheral *p)
{
    //open the /dev/mem folder with read/write
    if((p->mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to open /dem/mem, did you sudo?\n");
        return -1;
    }
    p->map = mmap(NULL,BLOCK_SIZE,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,p->mem_fd, GPIO_BASE);

    if(p->map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("mmap failed, MAP_FAILED\n");
        return -1;
    }
    close(p->mem_fd);
    p->addr = (volatile unsigned int *)p->map;

    return 0;
}
void unmap_peripheral(struct bcm2835_peripheral *p)
{
    munmap(p->map, BLOCK_SIZE);
    close(p->mem_fd);
}


//setting the pin as input
void input_GPIO(int gpio_numb)
{
    *(gpio.addr + ((gpio_numb)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((gpio_numb)%10)*3));
}
//setting the pin as output
void output_GPIO(int gpio_numb)
{
    input_GPIO(gpio_numb);
    *(gpio.addr + ((gpio_numb)/10)) |=  (1<<(((gpio_numb)%10)*3));
}
//setting the pin to HIGH
void high_GPIO(int gpio_numb)
{
    *(gpio.addr + 7) = 1 << gpio_numb;
}
//setting the pin to LOW
void low_GPIO(int gpio_numb)
{
    *(gpio.addr + 10) = 1 << gpio_numb;
}
//reading the state of the pin, 1 if HIGH, 0 if LOW
int read_GPIO(int gpio_numb)
{
    if(  *(gpio.addr + 13) & (1 << gpio_numb) )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

//this function is going to delay time in microseconds
void sleepMicro(unsigned int time)
{
    struct timeval now;
    struct timeval period;
    struct timeval end;

    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    period.tv_sec = time / 1000000;
    period.tv_usec = time % 1000000;
    timeradd(&now, &period, &end);
    while(timercmp(&now, &end, <))
    {
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    }
}

uint8_t dht11_data[5]={0,0,0,0,0};//changed
void read_DHT11()
{
    //TODO make the function to return value to the parameteres, reference
    //TODO how to convert char floats to floats
    uint8_t laststate = 1;
    uint8_t counter = 0;
    uint8_t j = 0;
    uint8_t i = 0;
    float farenheit;

    /* From the DHT11 datasheet we read */
    dht11_data[0] = 0;  //The 8bit humidity integer data
    dht11_data[1] = 0;  //The 8bit humidity decimal data
    dht11_data[2] = 0;  //The 8bit temperature integer data
    dht11_data[3] = 0;  //The 8bit temperature decimal data
    dht11_data[4] = 0;  //The 8bit parity bit

    /* Sending initialization signal  */
    output_GPIO(4);/* set the pin as output */
    low_GPIO(4); /* pull the pin LOW  */
    sleepMicro(18 * 1000);/* delay for 18 milliseconds which are 18000 microseconds */
    high_GPIO(4); /* pull the pin HIGH */
    sleepMicro(40);/* delay for 40 microseconds */
    input_GPIO(4);/* set the pin as input so we can read output from the sensor */
    for(i = 0;i < MAXTIMINGS;i++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        while(read_GPIO(4) == laststate)
        {
            counter++;
            sleepMicro(1); //delay for 1 micro second;
            if(counter == 255)
            {
               break;
            }
        }
    laststate = read_GPIO(4);
    if(counter == 255)
    {
        break;
    }
    // top 3 transistions are ignored
    if( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
    {
        dht11_data[j/8] <<= 1;
        if(counter > 16)
        {
           dht11_data[j/8] |= 1;
        }
        j++;
    }
  }
    // Check if the data is correct acording to datasheet
    if( (j >= 40) && (dht11_data[4] == ((dht11_data[0] + dht11_data[1] + dht11_data[2] + dht11_data[3]) & 0xFF)))
    {
        farenheit = dht11_data[2]*9./5.+32;
        printf("Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d *C (%.1f *F)\n",dht11_data[0],dht11_data[1],dht11_data[2],dht11_data[3],farenheit);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data not correct!\n");
    }
}

int main()//changed
{
    printf("DHT11 on a Raspberry Pi 2\n");
    map_peripheral(&gpio);
    while(1)
    {
        read_DHT11();
        sleep(1);
    }

   return 0;
}
```